# Swift 4 - Override AVAudioRecorder recording

Tags: ios, swift

I am using AvAudioRecorder for to make audio recordings in my iOS Application. I am able to make an initial recording, but I want to give the user the option of re-recording.

I have these defined:

```
var recordingSession: AVAudioSession!

var audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder!
```

and In my viewDidLoad I have this:

```
recordingSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

        do {

            try recordingSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)

            try recordingSession.setActive(true)

            recordingSession.requestRecordPermission() { result in

                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    if(result == true)
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }

                }

            }

        }
        catch
        {

        }
```

and then I have my record button:

```
@IBAction func recordButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        if audioRecorder == nil {
            startRecording()
        } else {
            finishRecording(success: true)
        }

    }
```

and here are my start recording and finished recording methods:

```
func startRecording() {

        audioFilename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("recording.m4a")

        let settings = [
            AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
            AVSampleRateKey: 12000,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
            AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
        ]

        do {

            audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: audioFilename, settings: settings)
            audioRecorder.delegate = self
            audioRecorder.record()

            recordButton.setTitle("Tap to Stop", for: .normal)

        } catch {

            finishRecording(success: false)

        }
    }

    func finishRecording(success: Bool) {

        audioRecorder.stop()
        audioRecorder = nil

        if success {
            recordButton.setTitle("Tap to Re-record", for: .normal)

            audioSlider.isHidden = false
            playButton.isHidden = false
            uploadButton.isHidden = false

            do {

                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

                self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioFilename)
                self.audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()

            }catch{

            }


        } else {
            recordButton.setTitle("Tap to Record", for: .normal)
        }
    }
```

The problem is whatever I try to re-record it does't. I tried setting the audioRecorder to nil after it was done recording, but that didn't help at all.

Comment: This is not an answer but why do you have `setActive(true)` in finish recording plus you never stop the recording once it started

Comment: you need to check if recording instead of checking if nil here is the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiorecorder/1390313-recording)

Comment: I have encountered a case when trying to re-record audio AVAudioRecorder APPENDED new audio to the existing file. Although the documentation says .record() method should overwrite a file if exists:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiorecorder/1389435-preparetorecord